# Postman: Get array values from JSON Array and set them as postman variables

Tags: javascript, postman

I have the same question as this

[postman get values from array and set it,dynamically ,on env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775823/postman-get-values-from-array-and-set-it-dynamically-on-env-variables?newreg=df999a6b0b24402786167684ac06de69)

But I can't find out how to modify the best answer's method for myself.

JSON:

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "requestId": "5c871f361ed2196e43a00982"
},
"response": {
    "venues": [
        {
            "id": "536e7cac498ea9201478f0bb",
            "name": "Yeni Camii Alımyeri 1",
            "location": {
                "lat": 41.06841467513242,
                "lng": 40.69481069825992,
                "labeledLatLngs": [
                    {
                        "label": "display",
                        "lat": 41.06841467513242,
                        "lng": 40.69481069825992
                    }
                ],
                "distance": 60953,
                "cc": "TR",
                "country": "Türkiye",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "Türkiye"
                ]
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff3",
                    "name": "Town",
                    "pluralName": "Towns",
                    "shortName": "Town",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/neighborhood_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ],
            "referralId": "v-1552359222",
            "hasPerk": false
        },
        {
            "id": "5a22b75566611634a15d1f68",
            "name": "Osmançavuş Mah.",
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.714043,
                "lng": 41.209717,
                "labeledLatLngs": [
                    {
                        "label": "display",
                        "lat": 40.714043,
                        "lng": 41.209717
                    }
                ],
                "distance": 64990,
                "cc": "TR",
                "city": "Erzurum",
                "country": "Türkiye",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "Erzurum",
                    "Türkiye"
                ]
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff3",
                    "name": "Town",
                    "pluralName": "Towns",
                    "shortName": "Town",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/neighborhood_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ],
            "referralId": "v-1552359222",
            "hasPerk": false
        },
        {
            "id": "55e0acd1498e06a1c0bd34ca",
            "name": "Ören Beldesi",
            "location": {
                "lat": 41.17862276665214,
                "lng": 40.886770827531386,
                "labeledLatLngs": [
                    {
                        "label": "display",
                        "lat": 41.17862276665214,
                        "lng": 40.886770827531386
                    }
                ],
                "distance": 78451,
                "cc": "TR",
                "country": "Türkiye",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "Türkiye"
                ]
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff3",
                    "name": "Town",
                    "pluralName": "Towns",
                    "shortName": "Town",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/neighborhood_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ],
            "referralId": "v-1552359222",
            "hasPerk": false
        },
        {
            "id": "53e33833498ec6568c338076",
            "name": "Mapsino Köy Çıkışı",
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.81617736816406,
                "lng": 40.26142501831055,
                "labeledLatLngs": [
                    {
                        "label": "display",
                        "lat": 40.81617736816406,
                        "lng": 40.26142501831055
                    }
                ],
                "distance": 34825,
                "cc": "TR",
                "country": "Türkiye",
                "formattedAddress": [
                    "Türkiye"
                ]
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff3",
                    "name": "Town",
                    "pluralName": "Towns",
                    "shortName": "Town",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/neighborhood_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ],
            "referralId": "v-1552359222",
            "hasPerk": false
        }
    ],
    "confident": false
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of response.venues.id and sometimes I end up having to create 29 variables manually.

If someone can show me how to edit this code to work with my JSON response that would be great.

```
let idCount = 1
let nameCount = 1
let typeCount = 1
_.each(_.first(pm.response.json()).variables, (arrItem) => {
pm.environment.set(`varID${idCount ++}`,  arrItem.id);
pm.environment.set(`varName${nameCount ++}`, arrItem.name);
pm.environment.set(`varType${typeCount ++}`, arrItem.type);
```

})

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Do you want a single array with all the Ids?
For eg.: `idArr = ['536e7cac498ea9201478f0bb', '5a22b75566611634a15d1f68',...]` ?
Or you just want each Id stored as a variable (and no other data is required) ?

Comment: @SivcanSingh Yeah, my outcome is to have all the id's set as Postman variables. If you aren't familiar with Postman then just as a variable will do :)

Comment: Yeah, I have some idea about postman. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your existing script with the following:

```
let responseBody = pm.response.json(),
  venues = _.get(responseBody, 'response.venues');

_.forEach(venues, (venue, index) => {
    pm.environment.set(`varID${++index}`,  venue.id);
});
```

This will store all your ids as variables in the environment, which will show up like so: 
[image: Environment variables]

*Explanation:*

Firstly, we're getting the `venues` out of your response body to easily run a loop over it.
Then we just run a simple forEach loop over the items in the array and store the corresponding ID of each array item in the environment variable.

We're using [`lodash library`](https://lodash.com) for functions like `_.get and _.forEach`  which is built into postman.

Comment: @ZakhZ I just updated the script right now, can you re-copy it and let me know?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thankyou for your help. It worked the first time, it's just I forgot to add " let idCount = 1"

Comment: You're welcome.
I removed the dependency of `idCount` variable totally and moved it internally and local to the forEach loop by using the second argument of the callback function i.e `index`. Keeps the code neat and readable too. :)